# How to check if a radio button is selected or not through xquery

Tags: html, xquery

I have an HTML file that has 2 radio buttons and one submit button. 
Ascending and descending.

How can I check which radio button is selected on run time in xquery, so that I can call xquery accordingly

Here is the basic xquery

```
            for $x in fn:doc() 
            order by (fn:document-uri($x)) ascending
            return tokenize(fn:document-uri($x),"/")[last()]
```

How to incorporate code to check radio button in this.?

Comment: Please provide an example, so we can understand the document's structure, and give more details on your XQuery implementation and what interface is used to transmit the data: are you using HTTP GET/POST requests, do you query local files?

Answer (score 0):

Jeans' comment above has a point, more information would be helpful. I've assumed a general example;
If you want to get the elements' value based on if it is checked, you can do something like this:

```
let $doc :=
<form>
  <input checked='true'>data1</input>
  <input>data2</input>
  <input>data3</input>
</form>
return

$doc/input[./@checked="true"]/xs:string(.)
(:The response will be - data1 :)
```

This will filter out the document based on if the checked attribute is true.